# How to display list items in view passed from the controller ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developing MVC app.

I want to create the list in the controller and pass it to the view.

I have written the method in the controller but dont know how to call it form view and display the value which it return.

Method in controller.

```
public List<Invoice> GetInvoiceList(int Pid)
        {
            List<Invoice> Invoices = new List<Invoice>();          
            var InvoiceList = (from i in db.Invoices
                          where i.PaymentAdviceId == Pid 
                          select i);
            Invoices = InvoiceList.ToList();

            return (Invoices);
        }
```

View Code

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Advice No
                  </th>
                    <th>
                     Invoices
                    </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>

             @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdviceNo)
                        </td>

                       I wan to call the controller method GetInvoiceList here and
                       want to display list items here... 
                        <td>


                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Comment: You should look into ajax for something like this.

Comment: ajax ? I dont think so...

Comment: why not? you are calling a server function from the html on load correct? I think I may be mistaken as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: ya but, I dont think ajax is req. I passing the list from controller, I just want to show it using loop.

Comment: Wait are you trying to call the function you list from within the view, or have you called that function in your controller for this view and added it to the viewmodel to this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a PartialView to your project that has it's model set to `List<Invoice>`

then modify your code:

```
    public PartialViewResult GetInvoiceList(int Pid)
    {
        List<Invoice> Invoices = new List<Invoice>();          
        var InvoiceList = (from i in db.Invoices
                      where i.PaymentAdviceId == Pid 
                      select i);
        Invoices = InvoiceList.ToList();

        return PartialView("partialViewName", Invoices);
    }
```

in your other view:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdviceNo)
        </td>
        <td> @Html.Action("GetInvoiceList", new {Pid = item.id})</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I have tried the same it showing error- **Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'**

Comment: `@Html.RenderAction("GetInvoiceList", new {Pid = item.id})` in view

Comment: Is that the exact code you use? Does item.id exist or is the id called differently? I just used id because I have no knowledge about your Model, except that the item has an AdviceNo....

Comment: Sorry... my bad, I've revised my answer. RenderAction should've been Action instead.

Comment: changed but still error occurring - `{"The partial view 'partialViewName' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:\r\n~/Views/PaymentAdvice/partialViewName.aspx\r\n~/Views/PaymentAdvice/partialViewName.ascx\r\n~/Views/Shared/partialViewName.aspx\r\n~/Views/Shared/partialViewName.ascx\r\n~/Views/PaymentAdvice/partialViewName.cshtml\r\n~/Views/PaymentAdvice/partialViewName.vbhtml\r\n~/Views/Shared/partialViewName.cshtml\r\n~/Views/Shared/partialViewName.vbhtml"}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29362/discussion-between-major-byte-and-user1650894)

Comment: I have to create separate Partial view for it ?